# processing messages received via tcp (right datatype, approach etc explanation inside)

Tags: apache-camel, netty

Currently I'm receiving messages over tcp in a self written component that allows me to use `Netty` as a TCP server producer.

the messages i receive are formatted in `XML` style, for example:

```
<customheader>
<someattribute></someattribute>
</customheader>
<custombody>
</custombody>
```

The messages I receive are stored in a `byte[]` and to send it to another endpoint I create a new exchange via:

```
Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(endpoint);
exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate().sendBody("someendpointuri", receivedbytes);
```

now my questions:

- Is my approach with the new exchange correct?
- If want to for example get rid of the header or use other camel components, do I need to convert the `receivedbytes` from `byte[]` to a different datatype or is `byte[]` okay?
- If i want to remove the custom header can i use the remove header component from camel?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an new Exchange, but you're not actually using it. Instead, you only use it to access CamelContext. The method `sendBody` is creating a new Exchange for you and it is this Exchange that is actually being sent to endpoint specified by `someendpointuri`. Note that [you should not create a new producer template](http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html) every time you want to send a message.

When you say that you store messages as `byte[]`, I assume you're storing it inside Message body. In this case you store both `customheader`s and `custombody` as `byte[]` and Camel treats them both as Message body, not headers.

If you want to use Camel header-related components or language constructs, you need to parse your `customheader`s and then set them on the Message as headers by using `Exchange.getIn().setHeaders()` ([see API](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Message.html#setHeaders%28java.util.Map%29) with a note about this). If you do that, you would probably only want to set content of `custombody` in the `Exchange.getIn().setBody()`.

If you do these changes in your custom component, your component will now be handling this specific XML format only. If you want to keep your component generic, you can instead implement a custom [DataFormat](http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html) and call `marshal()` and `unmarshal()` in your routes. I think [SOAP DataFormat](http://camel.apache.org/soap.html) does something very similar.